# eBay API getProductDetails does not return product

Tags: rest, http, ebay-api

Hello I am trying to get this `getProductDetails` call to work:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/marketplacecatalog/ProductService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=getProductDetails&SERVICE-VERSION=1.3.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=MY-APP-ID&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-MOTOR&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&productDetailsRequest.productIdentifier.ISBN=9781477838662
```

I am trying to get [this book](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-Don-Diablo-by-Max-Brand-Paperback-Book-English-Free-Shipping-/361527675588?hash=item542cba8ac4:g:w6wAAOSwWBJXA7W8) by ISBN, but the call does not return the product and I am unable to make it work. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the API to search the eBay Motors site where the product does not exist. You need to direct your request to the eBay.com site. This is controlled via the GLOBAL-ID parameter and it needs to be:

```
  GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US
```